# unable to load configuration from from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(4)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask application to an Ubuntu server (AWS) use docker-ce. Earlier after making the container i was able to access at web, but now i'm getting the error as Method Not Allowed.

This is my uwsgi config:

```
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 664
cheaper = 0
processes = 50
master = false
```

My nginx sever block configuration:

```
server {
    listen 5222:80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/Email.sock;
    }
}
```

This is what i am getting when i am running the docker log :

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Aug 19 11:24:17 2019] ***
compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170516 on 16 May 2019 03:07:24
os: Linux-5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019
nodename: 7a7ba8e012f8
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 12
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 3.6.8 (default, May  8 2019, 05:35:00)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x556a7fe8ef70
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /app/uwsgi.ini
unable to load configuration from from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(4)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py:15: DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x556a7fe8ef70 pid: 10 (default app)
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 10, cores: 1)
2019-08-19 11:24:19,262 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2019-08-19 11:24:19,262 INFO success: uwsgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 1/1] 192.168.0.112 () {42 vars in 1684 bytes} [Mon Aug 19 11:24:24 2019] GET / => generated 1080 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 81 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
192.168.0.112 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1080 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
192.168.0.112 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:24:24 +0000] "GET /static/css/index.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1158 "http://192.168.0.112:5222/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
192.168.0.112 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:24:24 +0000] "GET /static/assets/Email_Traige_System_bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 132047 "http://192.168.0.112:5222/static/css/index.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 2/2] 192.168.0.112 () {40 vars in 1622 bytes} [Mon Aug 19 11:24:24 2019] GET /favicon.ico => generated 232 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
192.168.0.112 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:24:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 3/3] 192.168.0.112 () {48 vars in 1841 bytes} [Mon Aug 19 11:24:42 2019] POST / => generated 178 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 405) 3 headers in 108 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
192.168.0.112 - - [19/Aug/2019:11:24:42 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 178 "http://192.168.0.112:5222/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" "-"
```

I was earlier able to access my API on the web but now i am getting this error. "Method Not Allowed".

My Flask Code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from flask import jsonify
import json
# import numpy as np
# from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def main_form():
    classifier = joblib.load("model_question_topic.pkl")
    text = request.json['textarea']
    result = classifier.predict([text])[0]
    #return render_template('result.html', result=result)
    return json.dumps(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='5222', debug = True)
```

Comment: Can you show us you flask app's code. Especially the `/` route ?
Method Not Allowed means your route doesn't allow the method (POST) you used.

Comment: I've updated this with the flask code. @Taek

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `methods = ["POST","GET"]` to your `app.route('/')` decorator.
This is because by [default flask only accepts GETs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.route) and you are trying to POST to the route.

Comment: I tried doing this ``` @app.route('/', methods = ['POST']) ``` but now i'm not even able to access the index page which earlier i was able to. I was having issue in the second page when i prediction was running after entering text. @Taek

Comment: try `['GET', 'POST']`

Comment: I also recommend reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: The problem still persists as it doesn't go to the result page. I encountered a semaphore error in the logs. What can be the problem with that? Also, i used the same file structure and code and it was functioning properly but now it's not. @Taek

Comment: What do you mean it does'nt go to the result page ? Can you post your client application's code as well ?